# Dashed table column separator

Tags: tables, columns

I'm trying to create a table with dashed separators between my subcolumns. This is the kind of result I need (with `|` representing continuous separators and `╎` representing dashed separators):

```
+----------+-------------------+
|Data group|Stats              |
+----------+-------------------+
|A         |Q1   ╎Med    ╎Q3   |
+----------+-------------------+
|B         |Q1   ╎Med    ╎Q3   |
+----------+-----+-------+-----+
```

Is there a way to do it? A specific column separator to use in the `\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\multicolumn{number of columns}{align}{text}` to join multiple columns into one for a single row.

Comment: How does this answer the question?